# Firebase Prevent deletion of parent node if child node exist in firebase

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Rules to prevent deletion of parent node if Childs exist. I have a structure of firebase as below

```
Table :
{

$albumId : //Prevent deletion of this node if its child exist. 
{
   $childID : date; 

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent a node from being deleted if it has data in it:

```
".write": "data.exists() && newData.exists()"
```